# Possible reason for ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I know what a ConcurrentModificationException is. I had them before, I solved them before and I can get away with a Iterator.
However, In this case I don't understand why it's being thrown.

```
public boolean pointOnEdgeBlob(int x, int y, float edgeHitEpsilon) {

    init();

    for (int i = 0; i < nOfBlobs; i++) {
        Blob b = blobs.get(i);
         // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> here it calls the method where it goes wrong
        if (b.edgeHit(x, y, edgeHitEpsilon)) return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the edgeHit method that it in the blob:

```
public boolean edgeHit(float x, float y, float edgeHitEpsilon) {


    // quick test if it's worth it
    if (x < getMinX()-edgeHitEpsilon || x > getMaxX()+edgeHitEpsilon || y < getMinY()-edgeHitEpsilon || y > getMaxY()+edgeHitEpsilon) {
        return false;
    }

    // the last one should be connected to the first
    // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>> if i comment the part in the for loop then this get's the problem.
    PVector pre = cornerVectors.get(cornerVectors.size() -1);
    PVector cur;

    for (int i = 0; i < cornerVectors.size(); i++) {
        // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> on this line it throws
        cur = cornerVectors.get(i); 

        if(Blob.onLine(pre, cur, x, y, edgeHitEpsilon)) {
            return true;
        }

        pre = cur;

    }

    return false;

}
```

Update:

cornerVectors is a list view:

```
 List<PVector> cornerVectors;
```

It get's set with:

```
list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
```

There are no other threats running.

Here is the stack trace:

> Exception in thread "Animation Thread"
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException     at
>   java.util.SubList.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:752)   at
>   java.util.SubList.size(AbstractList.java:625)     at
>   nl.doekewartena.contour.scanner.Blob.edgeHit(Blob.java:229)   at
>   nl.doekewartena.contour.scanner.BlobData.pointOnEdgeBlob(BlobData.java:333)
>     at
>   nl.doekewartena.contour.scanner.ContourFinder.scan(ContourFinder.java:555)
>     at
>   nl.doekewartena.contour.scanner.ContourFinder.scan(ContourFinder.java:469)
>     at exclude.T04_ContourFinder.draw(T04_ContourFinder.java:38)    at
>   processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)     at
>   processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
>     at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)

Comment: So what is `cornerVectors`?

Comment: And there's no activity in other threads?

Comment: I'm fairly certain there's something you're not telling us.

Comment: Show us the exception stack trace.

Comment: And what is `list` that you take the `subList` from?  Is that being modified anywhere?

Comment: subList: The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

Comment: There you have it (in the exception stack trace) -- you (somewhere) modified the list that your `cornerVectors` sublist was taken from.

Comment: I added the stack trace. `list` is an `ArrayList<PVector>`.
It does get modified but not when I make the call to the method `edgeHit`.

Comment: Some time after you did the `subList` you modified `list`.  It doesn't have to be inside the failing method.

Comment: The point is that you shouldn't be modifying it after your `list.subList()` call.

Comment: So what you mean is that the problem can be caused somewhere else, and that this is the first place where it runs into a problem?

Comment: This is likely the first place you are accessing that returned `cornerVectors` list after modifying the original `list`.  Where you are modifying `list` prior to this, would it be possible to rather modify `cornerVectors` instead?  That should fix your problem.

Comment: @jpmc26 How is this java GUI? I work with processing. It has an animation thread, but I do everything on that thread. I never had a Thread problem before unless I created a thread myself.
Anyway, PseudoPsyche is right. And most thanks to Hot licks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you do

```
x = list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
```

the list should not be modified or it will throw CME when accesing  x

From the .subList javadocs:

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if
>   the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way
>   other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those
>   that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a
>   fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)