# How to deal with ConcurrentModificationException in this case

Tags: java, list, sublist

I'm working on a contour scanner. For every contour I want to save the corners / edge coördinates.
Instead of having an Array in the contour I have 1 big Array that I share. The reason for this is that it has to work on animations so this is for optimization.

The idea is that every contour get's a subList view of the big array.

I worked quite long on a class to make that easy and now I run into a problem:

```
ArrayList<PVector> vecs = new ArrayList<PVector>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  vecs.add(new PVector());
}

List<PVector> subList = vecs.subList(0, 5);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  vecs.add(new PVector());
}

// ConcurrentModificationException
for (int i = 0; i < subList.size (); i++) {

}
```

First, is it poor java design that it does throws the concurrent modification if I use `add(Object)`? This should have no influence on any subList I already have since it adds to the end right? (logical speaking). My point is, `add(Object)` can never influence an already excisting subList, only `add(index, Object)` can do that (and other things like remove, swap and sort).

Second. What would be a good way to deal with this? I could make the big array really big so it's less likely I need to add elements after I already made a subList but I wonder if there are any other good ways to deal with it.

Here is a class I made that had to make it easy for me but is making my life hard right now :)

```
public class ListDivisor<T> {

    List<T> list;

    int subListStartIndex = 0;
    int currentGetIndex = 0;

    InstanceHelper instanceHelper;


    public ListDivisor(List<T> list, InstanceHelper<T> instanceHelper) {
        this.list = list;
        this.instanceHelper = instanceHelper;
    }

    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


    public void reset() {
        subListStartIndex = 0;
        currentGetIndex = 0;

        if (instanceHelper.doResetInstances()) {
            for (T obj : list) {
                instanceHelper.resetInstance(obj);
            }
        }
    }

    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


    public List<T> getSubList(int size) {

        int fromIndex = subListStartIndex; // inclusive
        int toIndex = fromIndex + size; // exclusive

        for (int i = list.size(); i < toIndex; i++) {
            list.add((T) instanceHelper.createInstance());
        }

        subListStartIndex = toIndex;
        currentGetIndex = toIndex;

        return list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

    /**
     * Returns a subList starting where the previous subList ended till
     * the latest object added till then.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public List<T> getSubList() {
        return getSubList(currentGetIndex-subListStartIndex);
    }

    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


    public T getNext() {

        if (currentGetIndex >= list.size()) {
           list.add((T)instanceHelper.createInstance());
        }

        return list.get(currentGetIndex++);

    }

    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
        reset();
    }


    // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

    public interface InstanceHelper<T> {
        public T createInstance();
        public boolean doResetInstances();
        public void resetInstance(T obj);
    }

}
```

This is a small example of how to use the class:

```
 ListDivisor<PVector> vectorsDivisor = new ListDivisor<PVector>(
     new ArrayList<PVector>(), 
     new InstanceHelper<PVector>() {
            //@Override
            public PVector createInstance() {
                return new PVector();
            }

            //@Override
            public boolean doResetInstances() {
              return true;
            }

            //@Override
            public void resetInstance(PVector v) {
                 v.set(0,0,0);              
            }
     });

  PVector v = vectorsDivisor.getNext();
  v.set(1, 1, 1);

  v = vectorsDivisor.getNext();
  v.set(2, 2, 2);

  v = vectorsDivisor.getNext();
  v.set(3, 3, 3);

  subList = vectorsDivisor.getSubList();


  println("subList size: "+subList.size());
```

Comment: You know, you could just make a copy of the sublist, so that modifying the original won't cause a problem.

Comment: So, is your problem that using the sublist returned by `listDivisor`'s `getSubList` throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: @Edward - Yep - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262602/possible-reason-for-concurrentmodificationexception

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks, I figured it out. Sadly, I was out-FGITW'd while writing my answer.

Comment: @Edward - You will notice that I had already told Opie about the paragraph you and Stephen C posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the javadocs for `ArrayList.sublist`:

> "The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)"

In the implementation of `ArrayList` in the JVM that you are using, the "unspecified" semantics would appear to be that it throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

---

> First, is it poor java design that it does throws the concurrent modification if I use add(Object)?

Nope.  It is not "poor design".

They designed that way, deliberately, and for good reasons.  Furthermore, they **documented** that you would get unspecified behaviour if you did what you are doing.  And indeed, they have implemented the sublist class to *fast fail* if it detects a concurrent modification.  That is a good thing ... and entirely consistent with the API spec.

> This should have no influence on any subList I already have since it adds to the end right?

The problem is that while your example is (may be) safe, others are not.  And it is not possible to distinguish the safe and unsafe cases without adding a whole lot of additional infrastructure that would most likely make the `ArrayList` less efficient and more memory intensive for other use-cases.

(Hence my "for good reason" comment above.)

> Second. What would be a good way to deal with this?

It is hard to advise on that without understanding what your code actually needs to do.  But some generic alternatives spring to mind:

- Change your algorithm so that you don't use the List.sublist method; e.g. pass the first and last indexes of your notional sublists as parameters.
- Recreate the sublist object each time you update the backing list.  (Assuming that your updates to the backing list are really safe, then this is simple, and trivially correct ... assuming that you are not in the middle of using the sublist's iterator.)
- Change your code to use a `Queue` or `Deque` instead of a `List`.
- Implement your own List class (based on `ArrayList`) that doesn't throw CME's in this safe scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)) for ArrayList's subList method indicates that sublists should only be used while the structure of the backing list does not change:

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

Although you're right that adding to the end of the backing list shouldn't cause any unexpected behavior in sublists, Java is being pessimistic in this case and throwing the `ConcurrentModificationException` if you use the sublist in any way after the backing list changes. This is similar to the fail-fast behavior of list iterators, which is also explained in [the ArrayList docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), and it takes the view that it's better to fail cleanly rather than guess wrong about which concurrent modifications are "safe" and end up with unexpected behavior.

The easiest way to get around this, of course, is to finish all of your structural modifications to the big ArrayList before you create the sublists. Is there any reason you need to interleave creating sublists with expanding the ArrayList?

If you absolutely need to modify the big ArrayList while using subsections of it, I'd suggest not using subLists and just working directly with indices into the ArrayList. Each of your contour tasks would get the start and end indices of the subsection of the ArrayList it's working on, and it would go through them by repeatedly using `get()` on the big ArrayList. Iterating using explicit `get()` calls is important here, since iterating with an iterator or for-each loop will run into the same `ConcurrentModificationException` problem when you add to the end of the big ArrayList.

Alternatively, if you really need a `List`-compatible view of the sublists for each contour tasks, you could implement your own SubList class that does not throw an exception if its backing list gets `add()`ed to, and then write a small subclass of `ArrayList` that overrides `subList()` to return this instead. The source code for Java's `ArrayList` and `SubList` is [available online](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.subList%28int%2Cint%29), so you can refer to it if you want to make sure your SubList does everything Java's does.

Comment: The Java documentation is not specifically clear about *structural* changes. Though it includes an example to `clear()` parent items through the sub-list itself.

Comment: @S.D. I'm confused - doesn't the part of the documentation I quoted explicitly refer to structural changes? Also, the `clear()` example is modifying the sub-list, while OP asked about concurrent modifications to the parent.

Comment: This line in docs `undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list.` is confusing. Specially : `any way other than via the returned list`. So I think we need to ascertain whether operations on sub-list only alter that sub-lists' internal references or the parent list as well.